# How redis work?

Tags: redis, database, nosql

I am studying Redis, and I surprise how Redis works. I found that Redis, store recent data in cache in NoSQL format and have their own query for that. But I am curious about the following working:

1. How data store in persistence database. Do we need to fire same insert query in both the database?
2. If Redis uses NoSQL database is it compulsory that persistence database we are using is follow NoSQL structure?
3. How data synchronisation works between Redis database and persistence database?

Answer (score 0):

Redis offers persistence. There are several options depending on what exactly do you need. Here is the [official documentation](https://redis.io/topics/persistence).

Comment: You can just comment that out.